# R package: How to not show all the functions

Tags: r, package

I've made a package in R that consists of one main function and a lot of sub-functions that are used by that main function. I would like to make it so that users only see the main function while the other sub-functions are hidden to the user and are only used behind the scenes in the main function.

Comment: Create a Vignette that displays how to use your package... that way all the subfunctions are only introduced as you think http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/vignettes.html

Comment: You want to leave those functions unexported from the package namespace. [Here](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/namespace.html) is one intro to namespaces. (If you do want to see all of the functions in a package, including the unexported ones, you can use code like the following: `ls("package:stats"); ls(asNamespace("stats"))`)

Comment: I think I can solve using namespace. Thank you so much! :)